# How can i set the value of a datagrid cell using its Column and row index values?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can i insert a value into a specific datagrid cell by using the cells column and row indexs. I have the Row and Column index saved as ints.

I got the indexs as below. Im basically taking the cell value, the column index and the row index and sending as a serialized XML to java which is sending it back and needs to put it in the same cell.

```
        int column = dataGrid2.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        int row = dataGrid2.SelectedIndex;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you use DataGrid you can try it

```
DataRowView rowView = (dtGrid.Items[rows] as DataRowView); //Get RowView
rowView.BeginEdit();
rowView[col] = "Change cell here";
rowView.EndEdit();
dtGrid.Items.Refresh(); // Refresh table
```

Answer (score 2):

For a datagrid you access rows through the Items property. The cells are a collection on an item.

```
dataGrid2.Items[row].Cells[column].Text = "text";
```

This works as long as the data has been bound to the datagrid during the current page life-cycle. If this is not the case then I believe you are stuck walking the controls.

Answer (score 1):

To update a WPF DataGridCell programmatically, there could be many ways...

One of the ways is to update value in the bound data item itself. This way the property change notifications will fire for all subscribed visuals including the DataGridCell itself...

**Reflection approach**

```
 var boundItem = dataGrid2.CurrentCell.Item;

 //// If the column is datagrid text or checkbox column
 var binding = ((DataGridTextColumn)dataGrid2.CurrentCell.Column).Binding;

 var propertyName = binding.Path.Path;
 var propInfo = boundItem.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
 propInfo.SetValue(boundItem, yourValue, new object[] {});
```

For `DataGridComboBoxColumn` you would have to extract the `SelectedValuePath` and use that in place of `propertyName`.

Otherways include putting cell in edit mode and updating its content value using some behavior in the `EditingElementStyle`... I find this cumbersome.

Do let me know if you really need that.

Answer (score 1):

I used a variation based upon WPF-it's example to do the whole row and it worked!:

```
(sender as DataGrid).RowEditEnding -= DataGrid_RowEditEnding;

foreach (var textColumn in dataGrid2.Columns.OfType<DataGridTextColumn>())
            {
                var binding = textColumn.Binding as Binding;
                if (binding != null)
                {
                    var boundItem = dataGrid2.CurrentCell.Item;
                    var propertyName = binding.Path.Path;
                    var propInfo = boundItem.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                    propInfo.SetValue(boundItem, NEWVALUE, new object[] { });
                }
            }

(sender as DataGrid).RowEditEnding += DataGrid_RowEditEnding;
```

PS: Be sure that you use value types that are valid for the column (perhaps via a switch statement).

e.g.:
switch on propertyName or propInfo... propInfo.SetValue(boundItem, (type) NEWVALUE, new object[] {});

```
                    switch (propertyName)
                    {
                        case "ColumnName":
                            propInfo.SetValue(boundItem, ("ColumnName"'s type) NEWVALUE, new object[] { });
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
```